# Send an XML file using curl as metadata

Tags: bash, curl, put

'I have a huge XML file that I need to PUT at an endpoint. My curl command currently looks like :

```
curl -X PUT --user user:pass https://<end-point>/foo/bar/id \

    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \

    -d '{
  "medata": "${METADATA}"
}'
```

The `METADATA` I have is coming from :

```
METADATA=$(cat cost_meta.xml)
```

And `cost_meta.xml` roughly looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="_ydkjknxyky6vepon" 
.
.
index="0"/></md:SPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

The XML itself is perfectly fine. I've just trimmed it down to post it here.

When I run the `curl` command, I get the ERROR

```
Failed to upsert service provider due to invalid JSON input.zsh: command not found: -H
zsh: command not found: -d
```

So then I attempted it another way:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @cost_meta.xml -X POST --user user:pass https://<end-point>/foo/bar/id
```

But that gives me an ERROR of

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>417 Expectation Failed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Expectation Failed</h1>
<p>The expectation given in the Expect request-header
field could not be met by this server.
The client sent<pre>
    Expect: 100-continue
</pre>
</p><p>Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.</p>
</body></html>
```

So I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it a `PUT` or a `POST`? You use both.

Comment: Its supposed to be `PUT` as my first attempt. But I also tried with `POST`

Comment: Add quotes to your METADATA assignment - `METADATA="$(cat cost_meta.xml)"`

Comment: Are there blank lines in your code above the arguments to curl?

Comment: Yes the blank lines were an issue. But now Im getting `Invalid JSON provided as input. Could not parse the service provider's trust settings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to be fine, except the additional newlines and corresponding to the error message, add a `-H 'Expect:'`, so write

```
curl -X PUT --user user:pass https://<end-point>/foo/bar/id \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Expect:' \
     -d '{"medata": "'"$(cat cost_meta.xml)"'"}'
```

Comment: This surely took one of the errors away. But now Im getting `Invalid JSON provided as input. Could not parse the service provider's trust settings`

Comment: Corrected my answer.